# Find out where memory is consumed

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, memory-profiling

I have this relatively large numerical application code that may run for a few days and eventually spit out some numbers. The whole thing is written in C++, making use of a bunch of 3rd-party libraries, and compiled using GCC 4.6. The code uses shared pointers throughout.

Unfortunately, over time, the memory consumption of the code increases until all of the (shared) memory is used up, then crashes. Algorithmically, the code shouldn't build up memory over time, so there'll be a bug somewhere.

I did run a small example through valgrind's leak checker which reports that all should be fine. My thought was that shared pointers might unintentionally be created someplace, preventing from unneeded data from being freed along the process (but this is just a guess).

At the end of the day, I'm running out of ideas how to debug such a thing.
Any ideas?

Comment: Ask valgrind to report "still reachable" memory too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already have the valgrind toolsuite available, I would advise you to run the *massif* tool.

Massif will track the memory allocation origins and the report will indicate you how many bytes each allocation site/function created. This will help you understand where that memory blow-up comes from.

Answer (score 1):

GNU libstdc++ defaults to caching STL-related memory allocations, apparently for microbenchmark speed reasons.  However, the actual effect tends to be quite negative for both speed and memory footprint when using allocators such as tcmalloc and jemalloc.  tcmalloc disables this behavior by setting GLIBCPP_FORCE_NEW=1 and GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW=1 in the environment (for [libstdc++](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt04ch11.html#allocator.impl) versions 3.3 and 3.4, respectively), but I know of no other allocator that does so.  Therefore it generally a good idea to set the appropriate environment variable when launching your application.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have no leaks, you could face memory fragmentation.

If you are on Linux, I suggest to try [jemalloc](http://www.canonware.com/jemalloc/download.html) allocator. It runs great on Linux. It runs on many architectures, I used it successfully even on zLinux (on IBM zSeries mainframe). It's really easy to use - you don't even need to rebuild your application or any libraries, just build jemalloc and start your application with `LD_PRELOAD` set like this: `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libjemalloc.so <app>`